# Можно ли к изучению русского языка применить закон 20/80 (теперь и с задачей)?

Tags: методика

Закон Парето, или принцип Парето, или принцип 20/80 — эмпирическое правило, названное в честь экономиста и социолога Вильфредо Парето, в наиболее общем виде формулируется как «20% усилий дают 80% результата, а остальные 80% усилий — лишь 20% результата».

Можно ли этот закон назвать актуальным при изучении русского языка (конечно, не в точных цифрах, а принципиально)?

Мне кажется, что учебниках смешивается базовый материал и множество частных правил и исключений, не просматривается в них движения от центра к периферии, от общего к частному (а это основной закон развивающего обучения).

В результате людям трудно ориентироваться, и они смешивают принципиально важное и необходимое с факультативным и второстепенным, тратят большие усилия на то, что мало повысит уровень их знаний, и при этом проходят мимо того, без чего вообще обойтись нельзя.

Может ли помочь знание этого закона при изучении языка, да и вообще любого предмета? Сталкивались ли вы в жизни с его действием?

Comment: А вы имеете в виду изучение русского языка как иностранного (оно у нас хорошо разработано) или как родного (разработано плохо, многие носители даже элементарнейший ЕГЭ сдать не могут)? :) Если как родного, то, вот... читал я мнение, что система Розенталя _в принципе_ основана на заучивании исключений. Недостаток здесь в том, что наши уроки русского языка никак не учат, собственно, русскому языку и не дают ясного понимания системы — скажем, многие люди, уже давно окончившие школу, очень удивляются, когда узнают, что спряжение глагола нельзя узнать по окончанию в инфинитиве.

Comment: Я имею в виду изучение родного языка  в средней и старшей школе, когда уже имеется определенный багаж знаний и школьники могут быть мотивированы на обучение. Нужно что-то вроде дорожной карты, где дорожная карта – это наглядное представление пошагового сценария образовательного процесса. К примеру, изучается спряжение глагола.  Берется общая орфографическая карта, где обозначена эта тема, определяется базовая информация (20%)и дополнительная (80%). Ученик должен быть соучастником  процесса, а не объектом, в который учитель закладывает знания по своему усмотрению.

Comment: Серж, а разве иностранцы не знают, что такое ударный гласный?
Пить: пью, пьёшь, пьёт, пьём, пьёте, пьют  -  ударные окончания 1-ого спряжения. Молчать: молчу, молчишь, молчит, молчим, молчите, молчат -  
 ударные окончания 2-ого спряжению. Выбор личного ударного окончания делается по слуху, при этом по суффиксу спряжение не выбирается, да это и  нельзя сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе можно, но нужно понимать, что эти первые 20% усилий человек - носитель языка затрачивает еще до школы и в младших классах. Хорошо учившийся пятикласник способен сочинить тект почти любой длинны (про хватит ли усидчивости промолчу), так чтоб этот текст понял любой другой носитель языка, тоже самое касается и устной речи. Весь дальнейший уровень - это уже те самые 80% труда - 20% результата.

Comment: В идеале, наверное, так и есть: в начальной школе всё важно, да и дети еще не способны что-либо оценивать и выбирать. А потом (с 6-го класса) они начинают проходить всё заново, и здесь уже общая картина теряется, ориентиров нет, и всё русское правописание представляется бесконечной Terra Incognita со множеством правил и исключений: сколько я уже выучил, сколько мне еще надо выучить, где я сейчас?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что писать "не слишком неграмотно" никак не должно быть основной целью. Опыт общения, чтения, обсуждения, правки, — всё показывает, что часто и выпускники ВУЗов не могут написать хороший текст. И не важно, что написано всё без ошибок. Проблемы две: нет умения рационально мыслить и нет умения всё замысленное излагать. А ведь "русский язык" судя по названию, должен в основном учить именно использованию русского языка в разных его вариантах. Даже если принять правило, что ВСЁ пишется как слышится, не станут все ученики прекрасно и красиво писать.

Comment: @Shady_arc, я согласен с вашей репликой, но как она соотносится с текстом моего ответа? Я лишь утверждаю, что для общения вполне можно обойтись знанием русского языка на уровне младшей школы. Выразить на таком языке сложные мысли невозможно, но для этого как раз и необходимо дальнейшее образование. Человека пишущего на йазыке падонкафф поймут, но воспринимать серьёзно не будут.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласен с  Shady_arc  по поводу спряжения. Никак не могу понять правило: глаголы на *ить* относятся к второму спряжению, а глаголы на *ать-ять* ко первому.При этом оговаривается: ***Это верно только для глаголов с безударными личными окончаниями.*** Если личные окончания глагола ударные, то спряжение определяется по окончаниям***.Ладно, нам , носителям языка, не составит труда ( и то не всем) правильно проспрягать глагол, не зная какого он спряжения, мы это делаем механически. Но ведь для того , чтобы определить ударное окончание или нет, чтобы правильно его записать, мы должны знать к какому спряжению относится глагол.И как объяснить другим, в каких случаях случаях окончание ударное, а в каких - нет?! В испанском, например, очень четко сформулированное правило: глаголы на  ar - 1- спряжение, на er - 2-спряжение,  на ir -3 - спряжение. Так ,например,   глагол* спать* относится к II спряжению (сп-ишь), а глагол* пить* — к I спряжению (пь-ешь).

София, но как тогда объяснить, например, иностранцу, в каком глаголе личное окончание ударное, а в каком - нет? При этом не углубляться в научно -лингвистические дебри.

Comment: Глаголы в русском языке образуют СЛОЖНУЮ СИСТЕМУ СЛОВОИЗМЕНЕНИЯ, которая подробно изучается в общей грамматике. Там все глаголы в соответствии с их ОСНОВОЙ  делятся на 5 классов и  10 групп. Каждый класс или группа относится к определенному спряжению – первому или второму. Приведенная классификация глаголов НЕ ИЗУЧАЕТСЯ в средней школе.

Comment: В школьном курсе выбор спряжения делается УПРОЩЕННЫМ СПОСОБОМ по глагольному суффиксу как формальному признаку, причем это делается в том случае, если его личные окончания являются безударными.  Глаголы с ударным окончанием выбрали себе спряжение сами.  Таким образом, школьники должны понимать, что выбор спряжения - это эмпирическое (условное) правило, позволяющее простым способом определить спряжение, не изучая всю сложную систему.  В действительности спряжение глагола зависит от его основы.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что школьный курс имеет другие задачи. Наверное, сложноподчинённые предложения и причастия/деепричастия — единственный новый материал. В остальном курс обучает не русскому языку, а орфографии. Причём, видимо, бездарно: у нас не самая сложная система письменности, ей можно научить, наверное, за 4 года в достаточном объёме. Японский школьник за 10 лет учит 2000 иероглифов. А русский — учится писать безударные гласные, н/нн, ставить запятые и различать слитное/раздельное написание. Ещё он учит парцелляцию, метонимию и способы связи словосочетаний (зачем?).

Comment: Учит не очень хорошо, впрочем: мне взрослый человек с пеной у рта всерьёз пытался доказывать, что "Я *не профессиональный* лингвист" нужно писать только слитно. Похоже, школьные уроки отбивают мозг, и у человека правда создаётся ощущение, будто писать всё и всегда надо одинаково даже если это прямо противоречит тому, что вы хотите сказать. Тут вот лингвисты много поругались на тему:) http://postnauka.ru/talks/27840

Comment: Система обучения правописанию, действительно, бездарная, но здесь дело не только в педагогах. Наша орфография (в качестве  ОПИСАНИЯ существующей системы письма) как наука еще не состоялась. Нет четких определений, законы обозначены только в предисловии к учебникам, правила - это наблюдения за письмом, описание письма, но никак не понимание и не анализ. И это при том, что изучаемый материал точно невелик, его просто надо систематизировать и объяснить, научить решать задачи, а не заучивать решения.

Comment: И академики меня удивляют, сообщая, что грамматика школьникам не нужна, и это при том, что всё письмо построено на грамматике. А мне вот кажется, что такие академики нам не нужны.

Comment: Академики отмечают то, что та "грамматика", которая даётся в школе в значительной мере устарела и в головы детей впихивается по привычке. В математике не учат считать римскими цифрами (вот только геометрию до сих пор учат), в природоведении не изучают теорию плоской земли как центра вселенной. Как известно, для многих европейских языков грамматика строилась по латинскому образцу, т.е. находились аналогии с классическими понятиями. Но ведь ясно, что идеального соотвествия не будет! И если для общего ознакомления эту "простую" грамматику знать приятно и полезно, то превращать её в самоцель глуп

Comment: например, у нас всё стандартно было. Про "должен/нужен" мы ничего не знали, "предикативное что-то там" вообще ни разу не звучало. В принципе, их можно объяснять как краткие прилагательные, но можно бы и более новые сведения тоже дать. Впрочем, я доволен, что после 8 класса у нас русского не было — только литература. Предполагалось, что в процессе занятий математикой, физикой и литературой грамотно писать люди уж как-нибудь научатся. Ну худой конец, перечитают правила в справочнике.

Comment: >> Учит не очень хорошо, впрочем: мне взрослый человек с пеной у рта всерьёз пытался доказывать, что "Я не профессиональный лингвист" нужно писать только слитно. Похоже, школьные уроки отбивают мозг

Смелое заявление... А если Вы встретите взрослого человека, который не умеет решать квадратные уравнения? Мало ли кого мы встречаем, что же, во всех случаях школьные методики виноваты?

Answer (score 0):

А что такое "может ли помочь"? Как именно знание этого "закона" должно помочь?

Успокоиться на этих восьмидесяти процентах? Тогда (гы-гы-гы) я себя уговорю, что уже знаю 80 процентов, и вообще перестану заниматься языком. А на самом деле едва дотяну до 20... И я буду ох как не одинок!
Да и учителя, и авторы учебников тоже запросто себя уговорят, что 20=80, и очень просто.

Так что только вред, только вред...

Comment: Речь идет о том, что если разделить современный учебник орфографии на 100 условных страниц, то окажется основные (базовые) сведения будут заключены в 20 страницах. Освоив их, вы получите оценку "хорошо". Для того, чтобы получить оценку "отлично" вам придется выучить остальные 80 страниц.

Comment: Поставить-то "хорошо" можно. Но это же не будет "хорошо". Это будет даже не "удовлетворительно", это будет оценка, которой сейчас нет – "посредственно". Уверен в этом.

Далее. Цель школы – не только (и не столько!) давать знания. Цель – прокачивать мозги! А я соглашусь на четверку (плохо ли!), а оставшееся время что буду делать?

А если и в математике так сделать? А в географии просто выучить, что Волга впадает в Каспийское море, тем более что извозчики-то всюду довезут...

Comment: Интересно послушать ваши рассуждения, но мне они всё-таки кажутся немного субъективными. Поэтому давайте сделаем проверку в соответствии СО СЛЕДУЮЩЕЙ СИТУАЦИЕЙ. В учебнике  формулируется основное правило, которое охватывает 80% написаний и занимает 20%   текста и описание частных случаев, которые  занимают 80 % текста, но охватывают только  20%   написаний. Материал дается вперемешку.  Допустим, что человек выучил 60% всего материала и рассчитывает на заслуженную тройку. Какова ВЕРОЯТНОСТЬ того, что при написании диктанта он ее получит? Здесь есть математики? РЕШИТЕ, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, ЗАДАЧУ.

Comment: Я считаю, что если человек знает правило на 80℅ – он не знает его совсем. Я программист, если что. Программа не может работать на 80℅.

Да и надуманна эта ситуация. Что это за правило, которое охватывает 80℅ всех случаев? И как это можно не знакомиться с исключениями? Писать оловяный, деревяный, стекляный и получать за это "хорошо"?

Comment: >Я считаю, что если человек знает правило на 80℅ – он не знает его совсем. ... Программа не может работать на 80℅.

@Niemand, в этом и есть разница между точными и гуманитарными науками. В первых нельзя решить задачу на 80%, а во вторых - на 100%. Ни вы, ни я, ни даже София не имеете абсолютных знаний по орфографии и пунктуации, ни говоря уже об остальных разделах русского языка, что не мешает нам общаться и понимать друг друга.

Comment: А я не возражаю, чтобы Niemand "считал" так, как умеет. Например, Niemand вправе считать, что Земля покоится на трёх верблюдах.

Comment: Вот ненадуманная ситуация из практики. Выбор ПРЕ/ПРИ – очень сложная орфограмма, усваивается с трудом.  Попробуем сравнить две методики. (1)КЛАССИЧЕСКАЯ МЕТОДИКА: ПРЕ – 2 значения, ПРИ – 5 значений (для каждого слова очень долго перебираем 7 значений). (2) БАЗОВАЯ МЕТОДИКА 20/80 : ПРЕ – одно  обобщенное значение ПЕРЕХОДА, ПРИ – одно  обобщенное значение ПРИБЛИЖЕНИЯ (для каждого слова выбираем одно из двух значений). Вместо частных решений одно общее. Информации меньше, эффективность больше.

Comment: >> Информации меньше, эффективность больше.

Не могу судить об эффективности, может, она и больше, но где тут те 20℅, которые мы "недоучили"? Где я сделаю ошибку, занимаясь по "прогрессивной" методике?

Comment: >> @Niemand, в этом и есть разница между точными и гуманитарными науками. В первых нельзя решить задачу на 80%, а во вторых - на 100%. Ни вы, ни я, ни даже София не имеете абсолютных знаний по орфографии и пунктуации, ни говоря уже об остальных разделах русского языка, что не мешает нам общаться и понимать друг друга.

Это красивая фраза – про 80 и 100 процентов. Что такое "абсолютные знания", да ещё не по грамматике, а всего-то по орфографии? Если человек пишет ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ без орфографических ошибок – его знаний недостаточно? Почему?

Comment: >Если человек пишет ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ без орфографических ошибок – его знаний недостаточно?

@Niemand, смотря для чего. Для личного пользования 95% случаев достаточно даже писать без **существенных ошибок**. А если нужно проверять знания?

Можно ли написать *большевиЦкая будёновка*? Если не заглядывать в словарь большинство проверяющих учителей поставят ошибку, и будут неправы, так как подобное написание допустимо. Молчу уж про заглавные-строчные буквы, которые в нынешнем виде вообще почти не регулируются, Розенталевские правила в данном пункте во многом устарели, а Лопатинские не все приняли.